# C#/WPF opensource camera library

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, camera

I am not worked with .Net project for a while and now I need to use a library to show liveview from the webcam and take a picture or make a video. Can anyone suggest me a good opensource library for do that? After a quick search I found **AForge** library but I don't know if it is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Recommendation questions are off-topic.

Comment: thank you @DangerZone, can you explain me why?

Comment: I don't know the exact reasons. I'm sure meta has some posts on it though. Probably because there is no "right answer" and it usually leads to fairly open-ended and opinionated posts that aren't quite the right fit for the site.

Comment: [Sample with WebCam_Capture](https://www.sendspace.com/file/ax93i9)

Comment: @ciccioska could you try example?

Answer (score 0):

I used WebCam_Capture before;

WebCAM.cs:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using WebCam_Capture;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace controlPC{
 class WebCam{
private WebCamCapture webcam;
private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox _FrameImage;
private int FrameNumber = 50;
 public void InitializeWebCam(ref System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox ImageControl){
 webcam = new WebCamCapture();
  webcam.FrameNumber = ((ulong)(0ul));
 webcam.TimeToCapture_milliseconds = FrameNumber;
 webcam.ImageCaptured += new WebCamCapture.WebCamEventHandler(webcam_ImageCaptured);
_FrameImage = ImageControl;}
 void webcam_ImageCaptured(object source, WebcamEventArgs e){
 _FrameImage.Image = e.WebCamImage;}
  public void Start(){
 webcam.TimeToCapture_milliseconds = FrameNumber;
 webcam.Start(0);}
 public void Stop(){
 webcam.Stop();}
 public void Continue(){
 webcam.TimeToCapture_milliseconds = FrameNumber;
 webcam.Start(this.webcam.FrameNumber);}
```

MainForm.cs

```
using WebCam_Capture;
    void MainFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 webcam = new WebCam();
webcam.InitializeWebCam(ref pictureBox1);
}
```